# How to append to variable within http.get? (Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, http, variables, append

```
var content = 'Hi, welcome to my webpage.';
var options = {host: 'www.website.com', path: '/folder/song.mp3', agent:false};

http.get(options, function(r) {
  r.on('data', function() {
    if (r.statusCode !== '404') {
      content += '<a href="www.website.com/folder/song.mp3">Download</a>';
    }
  });
});

fs.writeFile('index.html', content);
```

So normally, if I want to write a static html webpage from a node.js script, this works perfectly. For some reason, however, if I try to append to content from within `http.get`, it doesn't work. The whole point is to check if the file/page exists from an external website, and if it does then to display a link to it. The code that checks for the existing file works just fine, but I can't append anything to an external variable it seems. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `end` event of http to indicate when you finish receiving data. 
As node is asynchronouse the `fs.writeFile` instruction is run before all your data is received.

Here's how you can do it:

```
http.get(options, function(r) {
  r.on('data', function() {
    if (r.statusCode !== '404') {
      content += '<a href="#">Download</a>';
    }
  });
  r.on('end', function() {
     fs.writeFile('index.html', content);
  });
});
```